# Use a custom display name (label) for VeeValidate 3 on errors

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

How do I change the "name" that is shown on validation errors. I know I can adjust it with the property "name" but I want to leave it the way it is to match it with validation errors from the backend. I do not want to change the attribute name in the backend to something descriptive. For users´ better understanding I want to use a more descriptive name on frontend errors.

I use Boostrap-Vue, Laravel 6 and VeeValidate 3. This is the code I use right now. So instead of having "**url** is a required field." I want to show e.g. "**Link** is a required field" without changing the *name* attribute.

```
    <validation-observer ref="observer" v-slot="{ passes }">

        <b-form @submit.stop.prevent="passes(onSubmit)">
            <b-row>
                <b-col sm="2" lg="3">
                    <label for="url">{{ $t('channel.label_create_url') }}</label>
                </b-col>
                <b-col sm="10" lg="9">
                    <validation-provider
                        name="url"
                        :rules="{ required: true, min: 11, regex: /^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ }"
                        v-slot="validationContext"
                    >
                        <b-input
                            v-model="form.url"
                            :placeholder="$t('channel.placeholder_create_url')"
                            type="url"
                            size="lg"
                            name="url"
                            id="url"
                            required
                            autofocus
                            :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
                            aria-describedby="input-url-live-feedback"
                        ></b-input>
                        <b-form-invalid-feedback
                            id="input-url-live-feedback">{{ validationContext.errors[0] }}
                        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
                    </validation-provider>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </b-form>
    </validation-observer>
```

Any hints are appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            <validation-provider
                vid="url"
                name="Link"
                :rules="{ required: true, min: 11, regex: /^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ }"
                v-slot="validationContext"
            >
```

You can use the `vid` attribute to identify the Validation Provider and then `name` will be used in the error messages only.

Comment: No, please read my question. I tried to explain that is not what I want. I want to keep "url" as the name attribute.

Comment: Could you use `vid="url"` instead?  It's not clear why you need the validation-provider to have the same name as your backend.

Comment: Something I often do is explicitly write the error messages and use `failedRules` to tell me which messages to display

Comment: The vid did the trick. If you change your answer I´ll accept it. Thank you!